# How can I split a string to store contents in two different arrays in c#?

Tags: c#

The string I want to split is an array of strings.
the array contains strings like:

G1,Active

G2,Inactive

G3,Inactive

.

.

G24,Active

Now I want to store the G's in an array, and Active or Inactive in a different array. So far I have tried this which has successfully store all the G's part but I have lost the other part. I used `Split` fucntion but did not work so I have tried this.

```
int i = 0;
for(i = 0; i <= grids.Length; i++)
{
    string temp = grids[i];
    temp = temp.Replace(",", " ");
    if (temp.Contains(' '))
    {
        int index = temp.IndexOf(' ');
        grids[i] = temp.Substring(0, index);
    }
    //System.Console.WriteLine(temp);
}
```

Please help me how to achieve this goal. I am new to C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly - we have an array of strings Eg:

```
arrayOfStrings[24] = 
    {
      "G1,Active",
      "G2,Inactive",
      "G3,Active",
       ...
      "G24,Active"
    }
```

Now we want to split each item and store the g part in one array and the status into another.

Working with arrays the solution is to - traverse the arrayOfStrings.

Per each item in the `arrayOfStrings` we split it by `','` separator.

The `Split` operation will return another array of two elements the g part and the status - which will be stored respectively into distinct arrays (`gArray` and `statusArray`) for later retrieval. Those arrays will have a 1-to-1 relation.

Here is my implementation:

```
static string[] LoadArray()
{
    return new string[]
    {
        "G1,Active",
        "G2,Inactive",
        "G3,Active",
        "G4,Active",
        "G5,Active",
        "G6,Inactive",
        "G7,Active",
        "G8,Active",
        "G9,Active",
        "G10,Active",
        "G11,Inactive",
        "G12,Active",
        "G13,Active",
        "G14,Inactive",
        "G15,Active",
        "G16,Inactive",
        "G17,Active",
        "G18,Active",
        "G19,Inactive",
        "G20,Active",
        "G21,Inactive",
        "G22,Active",
        "G23,Inactive",
        "G24,Active"
    };
}
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string[] myarrayOfStrings = LoadArray();
    string[] gArray = new string[24];
    string[] statusArray = new string[24];

    int index = 0;
    foreach (var item in myarrayOfStrings)
    {
        var arraySplit = item.Split(',');
        gArray[index] = arraySplit[0];
        statusArray[index] = arraySplit[1];

        index++;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < gArray.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} has status : {1}", gArray[i] , statusArray[i]);
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

seems like you have a list of `Gxx,Active` my recomendation is first of all you split the string based on the space, which will give you the array previoulsy mentioned doing the next:

```
string text = "G1,Active G2,Inactive G3,Inactive G24,Active";
string[] splitedGItems = text.Split(" ");
```

So, now you have an `array`, and I strongly recommend you to use an `object`/`Tuple`/`Dictionary` depends of what suits you more in the entire scenario. for now i will use `Dictionary` as it seems to be key-value

```
Dictionary<string, string> GxListActiveInactive = new Dictionary<string, string>();
foreach(var singleGItems in splitedGItems)
{
    string[] definition = singleGItems.Split(",");
    GxListActiveInactive.Add(definition[0], definition[1]);
}
```

What im achiving in this code is create a collection which is key-value, now you have to search the `G24` manually doing the next

```
string G24Value = GxListActiveInactive.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Key == "G24").Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

just do it :

```
 var splitedArray = YourStringArray.ToDictionary(x=>x.Split(',')[0],x=>x.Split(',')[1]);
 var gArray = splitedArray.Keys;
 var activeInactiveArray = splitedArray.Values;
```

I hope it will be useful

Answer (score 0):

You can divide the string using `Split`; the first part should be the G's, while the second part will be "Active" or "Inactive".

```
int i;
string[] temp, activity = new string[grids.Length];
for(i = 0; i <= grids.Length; i++)
{
    temp = grids[i].Split(',');
    grids[i] = temp[0];
    activity[i] = temp[1];
}
```